# Adding source attachments to SBT dependencies with explicit URL

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

Given a dependency, say:

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" % "bar" % "1.0" from "http://foobar.com/foo.bar.jar"
```

How may I also specify the sources artifact for the dependency?

Comment: did you try to add withSources() before or after from part?

Comment: Since this is an 'explicit URL' dependency, I would need to specify where the dependency source is located, which withSources doesn't allow. Next time I need this I'll be taking a look at [ModuleId.sources()](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/IvyInterface.scala.html#245913).

Answer (score 0):

I'm successed

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
   Seq(
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.0" from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/liftweb/lift-json/2.0/lift-json-2.0.jar",
 "foo2" % "bar2" % "1.0" from "http://127.0.0.1/static/itext-2.1.5.jar"
  )
```

}

(no .pom , only itext-2.1.5.jar file)

next, check you '.classpath'

my '.classpath' contain

> classpathentry path="MY_HOME/.ivy2/cache/foo2/bar2/jars/bar2-1.0.jar" kind="lib"

and I found ' bar2-1.0.jar' in /.ivy2/cache/foo2/bar2/jars/ folder

good luck.

Comment: The example dependency you provided is similar to mine and has the same problem -- source isn't specified.

Comment: No error, just no source jar, simply because none is specified. I appreciate your good will, but you misunderstood my question.